# Spotify command for discord.js v12.1.1

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: 'spotify',
        category: "fun",
        noalias: "No Aliases",
        description: "shows stats of the person listening",
        usage: "[no mention | mention (optional)]",
        accessableby: 'everyone'
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        let user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;

        if(user.presence.game !== null && user.presence.game.type === 2 && user.presence.game.name === 'Spotify' && user.presence.game.assets !== null) {

            let trackIMG = `https://i.scdn.co/image/${user.presence.game.assets.largeImage.slice(8)}`;
            let trackURL = `https://open.spotify.com/track/${user.presence.game.syncID}`;
            let trackName = user.presence.game.details;
            let trackAuthor = user.presence.game.state;
            let trackAlbum = user.presence.game.assets.largeText;

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor('Spotify Track Info', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/653135129870336031.png?v=1')
                .setColor("GREEN")
                .setThumbnail(trackIMG)
                .addField('Song Name', trackName, true)
                .addField('Album', trackAlbum, true)
                .addField('Author', trackAuthor, false)
                .addField('Listen to Track', `${trackURL}`, false)
                .setFooter(message.member.displayName, message.author.displayAvatarURL())
                .setTimestamp()

            message.channel.send(embed);
        } else {
            message.channel.send('**This user isn\'t listening to Spotify!**');
        }
    }
}
```

in discord version 12.1.1 it gives me error of "(node:8560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined" help me how to solve this

Comment: changed the code
https://hastebin.com/eqejuhiquc.js -- spotify updated code, but it shows that user is not listening on spotify, though i am. also no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in fact since discord.js v12 game has been removed from presence use:

```
user.presence.activities
```

Answer (score 0):

well i have made a better command which not only checks if the user is playing spotify or not but also games and whatever else the user is playing along with custom status go here to get it ---

https://github.com/FirezzzZ/1SHOT-Bot/tree/glitch